# Display a folder on a page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, document-library

This maybe the most basic question ever asked. I am using SharePoint 2016. How can I display a specific folder if I click on a page (or folder on a specific page?)

I have default view set up. The folder (which itself is a subfolder of a folder called 'Projects') is called 'Project 1'. I want the users to click on a top link called 'Project 1' and should be able to visit Project 1's files.

I've tried adding the 'Documents' web part and tried changing the view but this displays all folders. I want to display the 3 folders under Documents on 3 different pages. This is where I am stuck!

I am also okay if someone clicks a page name - it opens up a folder (by linking a folder to page name)

Thanks for direction/help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dingo – I’m trying to decipher your question.  My understanding is that you have a library titled “Documents.”  Inside the library there is a folder called “Projects.”  The “Projects” folder has three nested sub folders titled:  Projects1, Projects2, Projects3.  You want to:  1) Create views to the specific nested folders that display on the view selector menu (you said “top link” in your question), and 2) you want to add the “Documents” library as a web part on three separate web pages, with each page displaying one of the three nested folders.  Do I understand correctly? Assuming I do, read on…

## 1 – Create views to specific nested folders

Create three views, one for each of your nested folders.  Each view would use a filter.  The filter is show items when “Name” is equal to [folder name].  The result will be a view that displays the specified folder only. From there users can click into it see all the files housed there.

## 2 – Add the “Documents” library to a web page and show a specific view.

Add the “Documents” library to a web page.  Edit its settings and change the selected view to one of the three new views.

Answer (score 0):

use the Rootfolder query variable like so:

```
http://{yoursite}/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=**/Shared%20Documents/mydocument**&FolderCTID=&View={A4A4A2E6-AE49-4173-B738-A14A4A1A49A0}
```

You can change `/Shared%20Documents/mydocument` to `/Shared%20Documents/mydocument/folder/folder2/subfolder/subsubfolder/` as an example